# Can not start bat file after compile program

Tags: streamwriter

I use this part of code in order to make bat file that I want to start from my c# app

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("DBBackup.bat");
// Do not change lines / spaces b/w words.
strPG_dumpPath = "cd /D C:\\Program Files\r\n\r\ncd pgAdmin 4\r\n\r\ncd v4\r\n\r\ncd runtime\r\n\r\n";
StringBuilder strSB = new StringBuilder(strPG_dumpPath);
```

This code works fine when I start app from VS 2019 but when I compile application and make installation for another pc after installation this part of program does not work.
Please help me to solve this problem, thanks!

Comment: I'm not a c# expert, but some more details about "does not work" could be helpful. Where does it fail? what happens? Any errors?

And btw. you can wrap code snippets in ```.  this 3 fences at beginning and end to make it more readable.

Comment: As I said when start application from VS2019 I  am able to make backup PostgreSQL database. App make this "DBBackup.bat" where are several lines of code that make backup but when deploy app and install it from setup file application cannot make this batch file so I am not able to make backup of database.

Comment: Probably because it needs administrator pillage to run.

Comment: Toni you where right I found this 
"Tried this of giving full permssions to everyone on that folder but still getting same error. – Andrea Feb 4 '14 at 17:14"
I change permission to folder and code work fine, FULL PRIVILAGE